# Regex, match part of word with wild card after

Tags: php, regex

Let me preface this by saying that I suck at regex badly, I've maybe used it 4-5 times in my life.

Let's assume I have the following array:

```
$array = array(
    1 => 'ReactorCraft:reactorcraft_block_modelreactor', 
    2 => 'f5b2289c-c1aa-4498-9673-271be0aada6c',
    3 => 'A word'
)
```

I want to perform a `preg_match` on each element(already taken care of) with a pattern that will match `ReactorCraft`, **and only that**, followed by whatever, I don't particularly care what comes next, I'm only interested in the word `ReactorCraft`.

I've tried a very simple, and probably wrong, pattern:

`'/[^ReactorCraft*]/i'`

`'/[\\bReactorCraft\\b]/i'`

And that's about all my knowledge when it comes to regex.

Any nudging in the right direction is more than appreciated.

Comment: _“a pattern that will match `ReactorCraft`, and only that”_ – so what is your expected result then? If you only want to check if those strings _contain_ the text `ReactorCraft` – then use `strpos` to begin with, instead of regular expressions.

Comment: Good point...I was stuck on regex for some reason.

Comment: @Andrew, Are you matching a string or matching against an array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

matching a specific string with Regex is simpler that it seems:

```
preg_match("/ReactorCraft/u", $searchText)
```

That'll match it essentially.  If you want to make sure it's at the front of the sentence:

```
preg_match("/^ReactorCraft/u", $searchText)
```

You might want to consider strstr and strpos which might be faster.

Answer (score 0):

This will match everything after "ReactorCraft:" 
`Regex = "/(?<=ReactorCraft:).*/"`